# Canvas - how to draw line from click to click and change colour on new "route"

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas (see photo below) and I've been stuck for some time trying to get lines BETWEEN the circles that are drawn when the user clicks inside the canvas.

As can be seen from the example in the photo, that is what I would like to have inside my canvas also :

USER clicks BLUE - starts first point blue (x), continues to click inside the canvas along the grid adding more blue (x's) with blue lines between them.
(I also have no idea how to draw X instead of the circle I currently use)

USER clicks RED - starts first point red (o), continues to click inside the canvas along the grid adding more red (o's) with red lines between them.

USER clicks "Sterge" - canvas clears, grid remains.

[[image: see canvas here]]
My code so far :

```
var needFirstPoint = true;
var lineTo = [{}];

function drawNextLine(ctx, x, y) {
    if (needFirstPoint) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        needFirstPoint = false;

    }
    else {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

   $(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0);
    if (!canvas.getContext) { return; }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var drawGrid = function (w, h, id) {
        ctx.canvas.width = w;
        ctx.canvas.height = h;
        ctx.lineWidth = .1;

        for (x = 15; x <= w; x += 60) {
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, h);
            for (y = 20; y <= h; y += 20) {
                ctx.moveTo(0, y);
                ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            }
        }
        ctx.stroke();

    };

    drawGrid(450, 280, "myCanvas");

    var drawChart = function () {
        ctx.arc(lineTo[lineTo.length - 1].x, lineTo[lineTo.length - 1].y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    drawChart();

    document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('click', function () {

        $('#myCanvas').on('click', function (e) {

            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            drawNextLine(ctx, x, y);

            lineTo.push({ x: x, y: y });
            drawChart();

        });
    });

    document.getElementById('move1').addEventListener('click', function () {

        $('#myCanvas').on('click', function (e) {

            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
            drawNextLine1(ctx, x, y);

            lineTo.push({ x: x, y: y });
            drawChart();

        });
    });

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ì've simplified your code. I hope you don't mind. Next comes my code. I hope this is what you want.

```js
var lineTo = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $("#myCanvas").get(0);
  if (!canvas.getContext) {
    return;
  }
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var drawGrid = function(w, h, id) {
    ctx.canvas.width = w;
    ctx.canvas.height = h;
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (x = 15; x <= w; x += 60) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, h);
      for (y = 20; y <= h; y += 20) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(w, y);
      }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  drawGrid(450, 280, "myCanvas");
  
  

  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  
  

  var drawChart = function(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
  };

  $("#myCanvas").on("click", function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;

    drawChart(x, y);

    if (lineTo.length > 0) {
      var last = lineTo[lineTo.length - 1];
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(last.x, last.y);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    lineTo.push({ x: x, y: y });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canas>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> I need to have 2 buttons : Left and Right. When I click on Left, the Right path is stopped and Left path begins from a independent point.

I'm not really understanding this. This is what I understand:

I understand you need a button to delete the last point `sterge`.

You also need a button `dreapta` to begin a new path.

Here comes my code. Please read the comments.

```js
//this is an array of arrays
//when I click on the canvas a new point is pushed on the last array of this array
var ry = [[]];


var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
let w = (canvas.width = 450);
let h = (canvas.height = 280);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

drawGrid();



myCanvas.addEventListener("click", e => {
  var offset = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - offset.left;
  var y = e.clientY - offset.top;
  //a new point is pushed on the last array of ry
  ry[ry.length - 1].push({ x: x, y: y });
  // delete everything
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  // draw everything
  drawGrid();
  drawChart();
});

sterge.addEventListener("click", e => {
  //when sterge is clicked the last point from the last array is deleted
  if (ry[ry.length - 1].length > 0) {
    ry[ry.length - 1].pop();
  } else {
    //if the last array is empty I delete this array 
    ry.pop();
    //and then I delete the last point from the last array
    ry[ry.length - 1].pop();
  }
  // delete everything
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
   // draw everything
  drawGrid();
  drawChart();
});

dreapta.addEventListener("click", e => {
  //when dreapta is clicked, a new array is pushed into the ry
  ry.push([]);
});

function drawGrid() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (x = 15; x <= w; x += 60) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, h);
    for (y = 20; y <= h; y += 20) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, y);
      ctx.lineTo(w, y);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawChart() {
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  // for every array in the ry array
  for (let index = 0; index < ry.length; index++) {
    // for every point in the ry[index]
    for (let i = 0; i < ry[index].length; i++) {
      let l = ry[index][i];
      // draw the circle
      drawCircle(l.x, l.y);
      // draw the line
      if (i > 0) {
        let last = ry[index][i - 1];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last.x, last.y);
        ctx.lineTo(l.x, l.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawCircle(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<p><input type="button" value="dreapta" id="dreapta" /> 
<input type="button" value="sterge" id="sterge" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I am unable to test it atm. Will be back with feedback, it seems to do the trick :). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for such delay. I tested your code, it is better than what I had but not exactly what I need. 
The user has to be able to draw 2 lines, using 2 buttons - let's say Left and Right. 
When user clicks on Left and then on canvas for the first time it starts as a X (not circle), user proceeds to draw until the end of the grid and then clicks on Right.

Right now starts as a completely new line (FirstPoint I guess) with a circle(as you have made above) from wherever the user first clicks on canvas (after selecting Right). The lines must be independent from one another.

Comment: I still haven't figured this out.. any help would be greatly apreciated. I need to have 2 buttons : Left and Right. When I click on Left, the Right path is stopped and Left path begins from a independent point.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The code is quite different. For every new path you need a new array of points. When you click the button `dreapta` a new array is created and is pushed into the main array `ry`. When you click the button `sterge` the last point from the last array is deleted. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Omg, you are awesome ! Thank you very much. About the button confusion, I actually need 3 buttons, Left, Right and Delete (in my last comment I left the Delete one out). So the only thing I need now is to figure out how to add event to Stanga(Left) button so when it's clicked a new path begins (like when I click Dreapta now), but instead of the circle there is an X.

Comment: **Hint**: in my code the `drawChart()` function is using the function `drawCircle()`. A function can take another function as an argument. You can write another function `drawCross()` and call `drawChart()` with either `drawCircle` or `drawCross` as an argument. And btw. If you liked my answer please accept it.

Comment: Just noticed in console I'm getting an error after submitting a form that uses the canvas with the code above : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'w' has already been declared". If I comment out the code from above I no longer get the error.  Any thoughts ?
Edit. Error shows up after page refreshes and canvas grid is missing, just blank. Have to refresh page to get grid back.

Comment: Found the issue :
let w = (canvas.width = 450);
let h = (canvas.height = 280);

replaced with :
var w = (canvas.width = 450);
var h = (canvas.height = 280);

Comment: This is why is recommended using `let` instead of `var`. Is forcing you to declare a variable only once. Instead of changing `let w` with `var w` you may consider  renaming the second w to something else.

Comment: I will check that out later, atm am busy trying to get the second button to work.. so far I can click on canvas and they BOTH show up, half circle, because I haven't yet searched how to make an X :) so I put Math.PI * 1 AND the full circle..

Comment: So if I click Left for the first time I can add X--X--X or O--O--O for Right .. but when I change from Left to Right for ex and click on canvas, all the blue X's drawn turn into red O's...  and the other way around...red O's turn into blue X's... how can I stop this ?

Comment: Please ask this as another question, and add all the code you have till now. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I made a mess of your code probably...

link to new question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242476/canvas-separate-2-arrays-of-lines-onclick